# Implementing a vector autoregressive model where only one variable is of interest

Tags: vector-autoregression

I have a dataset of 100 different time series and I am trying to forecast only one of them.  However I think that the 99 other time series influence the one that I am interested in so I use a VAR model so that time series that I am interested in is a linear combination of its own lagged values and the lagged values of the other 99 time series'.  The intuition is that the added information from the other time series will improve the forecast performance (i.e. it will be better than the forecast performance of a simple AR model where only the lagged values of the time series of interest are included).  So my first question is whether this intuition is correct.  My second question is if there are any known methods to determine which time-series will improve forecast performance of the time series of interest and which will not (similar to how feature selection works).